# Nginx configuration issue for proxying IDM

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, rewrite

I was working on accessing IDM using nginx, but somehow css and js files are not able to redirect properly.My configuration in nginx is as follows:

```
location /idm/{

proxy_pass           https://keyrock-host:keyrock-port/;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host    $host;
proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
rewrite ^/$  $1/idm/$2 redirect;
}
```

But it is not working properly still.

---

Update 1:

```
172.16.40.7 - - [2019-04-01T11:34:01+00:00] "GET /stylesheets/bootstrap-select.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 564 "https://172.30.66.248/key/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36" "-" "0.000" "-" "-"
2019/04/01 11:34:01 [error] 15#15: *9 open() "/etc/nginx/html/javascripts/tour.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.16.40.7, server: , request: "GET /javascripts/tour.js HTTP/1.1", host: "172.30.66.248", referrer: "https://172.30.66.248/idm/"
172.16.40.7 - - [2019-04-01T11:34:01+00:00] "GET /javascripts/tour.js HTTP/1.1" 404 564 "https://172.30.66.248/idm/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36" "-" "0.000" "-" "-"
2019/04/01 11:34:01 [error] 15#15: *9 open() "/etc/nginx/html/javascripts/others/see_password.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.16.40.7, server: , request: "GET /javascripts/others/see_password.js HTTP/1.1", host: "172.30.66.248", referrer: "https://172.30.66.248/idm/"
172.16.40.7 - - [2019-04-01T11:34:01+00:00] "GET /javascripts/others/see_password.js HTTP/1.1" 404 564 "https://172.30.66.248/idm/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36" "-" "0.000" "-" "-"
```

It shows the files are not found :
 `*9 open() /etc/nginx/html/javascripts/others/see_password.js"`

---

**Update 2**: While accessing the backend application directly and observing the behaviour.

```
URL : 172.30.66.235:3443 ---> Home Page
After Login : 172.30.66.235:3443/idm
(During Login if I click anywhere, /idm remains appended to it and after logging out.)
URL after Log out : 172.30.66.235:3443  ; similar to homepage.
```

The code line that does the same is :

https://github.com/ging/fiware-idm/blob/7.5.1/routes/web/index.js#L23

Or you can access the link : https://account.lab.fiware.org/ (Global instance of Keyrock)

Comment: $1 and $2 in your `rewrite` are backreferences to the regex. But your regex has no matching groups to be referenced at. Could you supply us with URLs and what they supposed to look like in the backend?

Comment: Yes, for backend the url is : https://172.30.66.235:3443/ on (HTTPs) and the IP for nginx should be https://172.30.66.248/idm (on HTTPs) while accessing idm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding a new `server` block it should look like this. So you forward `/` to the same location `/` of your backend server just by calling a different name/IP. You should replace the name in `server_name` as well as the certificate files.

```
server {
        server_name subdomain.example.com;
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/your_certificate.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/your_certificate.key;

        location / {
           proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host    $host;
           proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
           proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_pass           https://172.30.66.235:3443;
        }
}
```

Comment: Sir, actually the requirement resists me from running this on root.However, the one which you have written on location / above makes it run in the earlier scenario also. But I need to have /idm/ with the URL appended everytime. You can check the working of IDM on https://account.lab.fiware.org/ . The one on my local  creates the same url after logging in and after logging out. Additionally, at code level when the user session is acquired it appends /idm to it only after logging in. https://github.com/ging/fiware-idm/blob/master/routes/web/index.js#L22

Comment: Also,if I remove the rewrite ^/idm(/.*)$  $1 break; in configuration and keeping the proxy_redirect, it still doesn't works. is it possible can we have a direct chat??

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
location /idm/ {
   proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host    $host;
   proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
   proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   rewrite ^/idm(/.*)$  $1 break;
   proxy_pass           https://172.30.66.235:3443;
   proxy_redirect / /idm/;
   sub_filter '="/' '="/idm/';
   sub_filter '= "/' '= "/idm/';
   sub_filter '=\'/' '=\'/idm/';
   sub_filter_once off;

}
```

Edit 1: Added `proxy_redirect`

Edit 2: Added `sub_filter` options

Edit 3: Changed `sub_filter` to replace all possible occurrences with the new location.

A nicer way would probably be [nginx_substitutions_filter](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/substitutions/) and a proper regex.

Comment: Hi Sir, it's not working still. While looking at the console in web-browser i get :  
GET https://172.30.66.248/javascripts/tour.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) for (approx. 25 files) that are mostly css and js. whereas, while accessing https://172.30.66.248/idm/javascripts/tour.js shows the content of file.

Comment: I've added `proxy_redirect`, try it pls.

Comment: Hi Sir, Still no success. IDM being a nodejs application https://github.com/ging/fiware-idm is still not loading css or js only.

Comment: I've added `sub_filter` options, pls try again :x

Comment: hi Sir, bingo! the first page gets loaded but after logging in or clicking on sign in or sign up it shows 404 Not found, but if I write idm in the url it displays. So, in these cases its not working, but from earlier, its loading all the css and js for front page.

Comment: It would be easier to use the vhost feature of nginx (using a different `server_name` (sub-)domain) than rewriting all content of the website because of the relative and absolute paths in the source code.

Comment: you mean to say, I should create a new server block in which we have the same contents as provided by you in location block  as above?

Comment: Again edited my post.

Comment: Hi Sir, The front page are loading and working properly. But login is not happening; as for example after logging in the URL is -> 172.30.66.235:3443/idm and during the login if I click on organizations option the URL is 172.30.66.235:3443/idm/organizations and  after logout 172.30.66.235:3443. I am unable to attach the screenshots.

Comment: Hi sir, how can we use nginx_substitution_filter for the same ? or is it possible that if we place a root directive (for eg: root /var/ ) settings inside the location block.

Comment: Hi @unNamed, fiware keyrock is working fine and thank you immensely for you help. Just wanted to know one thing that I am unable to understand the purpose of sub_filter '= "/' '= "/idm/'; 
   sub_filter '=\'/' '=\'/idm/'; Can you help me understand with it?

Comment: `sub_filter` is a simple replace tool. It replaces `= "/` with `= "/idm/`. It searches all the HTML transferred to the client for the specified text and replaces it. The client then uses the changed path to request resources.

Comment: Hi @unNamed can you help me with this last thread in nginx. https://serverfault.com/questions/963610/unable-to-run-wso2-ui-consolr-i-e-carbon-using-nginx-reverse-proxy-server

Comment: Hi @unNamed can you just help me with just on issue, in the above while configuring it with nginx, I am getting the- "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined " issue, can you please help me just with it?

Comment: This sounds like a javascript error. I cannot help you with that.