# Unable to run WSO2 UI consolr i.e carbon using Nginx reverse proxy server

Tags: nginx

I want to access wso2apim using reverse proxy server with following location.

https://wso2am:9443/carbon      --->      https://nginx-ip/wso2am/carbon

I have configured wso2am/store and wso2am/publisher using the following URL.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+the+Proxy+Server+and+the+Load+Balancer#ConfiguringtheProxyServerandtheLoadBalancer-Step1-CreateaSSLcertificatefortheloadbalancer

My nginx conf is as follows:

```
   location /wso2am/ {

            proxy_set_header   Host                $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host    $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            proxy_pass https://wso2am-host:wso2am-ip/;
            proxy_redirect https://$http_host/carbon/carbon/ /wso2am/carbon/;

          proxy_redirect https://$http_host/wso2am/ /wso2am/;
          proxy_redirect https://$http_host/ /wso2am/;



            proxy_redirect https://$http_host/store/ /wso2am/store/;
            proxy_redirect https://$http_host/publisher/ /wso2am/publisher/;

             proxy_cookie_path / /wso2am/;

   }
```

But after configuring and accessing it, I login to the https://nginx-ip/wso2am/carbon. Then, after logging in I get logged out if I click anywhere.

Can someone assist me with configuring it?

Comment: you might need to edit `<WebContextRoot>/</WebContextRoot>` `/repository/conf/carbon.xml`

Comment: my bad `<ProxyContextPath>/wso2am</ProxyContextPath>`

Comment: [https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+the+Proxy+Server+and+the+Load+Balancer](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+the+Proxy+Server+and+the+Load+Balancer)

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [my answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58627428/7648881)

I faced the very same issue with both **wso2am** and **wso2ei**. I am pretty sure that we need to edit `/repository/conf/carbon.xml` in this section (I must admit that the comments are not crystal clear):

```xml
<!--
       Webapp context root of WSO2 Carbon management console.
    -->
    <WebContextRoot>/wso2am</WebContextRoot>

<!--
        Proxy context path is a useful parameter to add a proxy path when a Carbon server is fronted by reverse proxy. In addition
        to the proxy host and proxy port this parameter allows you add a path component to external URLs. e.g.
            URL of the Carbon server -> https://10.100.1.1:9443/carbon
        URL of the reverse proxy -> https://prod.abc.com/appserver/carbon

    appserver - proxy context path. This specially required whenever you are generating URLs to displace in
    Carbon UI components.
    -->

        <MgtProxyContextPath>/</MgtProxyContextPath> 
        <ProxyContextPath>/wso2am</ProxyContextPath>
```

The following works if your Nginx listen to 443 in SSL mode (couldn't do it with HTTP because of the redirections -> make a self signed certificate if you plan to use it on a local network)

```
    location /wso2am {
        proxy_pass https://wso2_apimanager_container:9443;
        proxy_set_header   Host                $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host    $host;
        proxy_ssl_verify   off;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

It works but I am not completely sure why. Can someone explain to me in which aspect `<MgtProxyContextPath>` differs from `</MgtProxyContextPath>` and from `<WebContextRoot>`?

**Subsidiary**: is there any way to access carbon with HTTP instead of HTTPS and let Nginx deal with certificates (mights ease the integration in my case)